# Protractor passing parameters in script run command

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I need to pass the credentials in command running a script.

For now, I am using in protractor file following part:

```
onPrepare: function () {
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({
        spec: {
            displayStacktrace: true
        }
    }));
    if (browser.params.Url == 'http://devel/') {
        browser.params.webmaster='abc';
        browser.params.webmaspass='foo';
    }
    //(other environments)
    else {
        console.log('-------------error during log in');
    }*/
}
```

and it was working fine, but I need to change it - I can't pass credentials in this way. I thought about changing it to:

```
    if (browser.params.Url == 'http://devel/') {
        browser.params.webmaster='';
        browser.params.webmaspass='';
    }
```

and run the script using

`npm run dev-script --browser.params.Url='http://devel/' --browser.params.webmaster='abc' --browser.params.webmaspass='foo'`

where package.json I have:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
     "dev-script": "protractor --params.Url=http://devel/ --browser.params.webmaster='' --browser.params.webmaspass=''"
  },
```

(or any variation) But it fails - I can't update params during running script, I need to write down the credentials in the code (which I find a little unsafe)

I found issues like [Protractor needs password for login => insecure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37944386/protractor-needs-password-for-login-insecure) but it about Google Auth problems

Any idea?

Comment: If you have a "test" account for doing tests, then there is nothing unsecure about storing passwords in configuration file.

Comment: Yes, I know, but due to security reasons in a company, I can't store it in this way :(

Comment: Duplicate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50241305/pass-jenkins-build-number-to-protractor-for-saucelabs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the variable assignment in the `onPrepare`. You are overwriting what you are passing in from the command line by setting it to an empty string.

When you pass them in from the command line they will be availble on the `params` object. There is no need to set them again in your `onPrepare`. Add a `console.log()` in your `onPrepare` and you will see.

Run it from the command line like this: `protractor conf.js --params.webmaster=abc --params.webmaspass=foo --params.url=http://devel/`

Again, if you log them in your `onPrepare` you will see that it is working. The way you currently have it you are just overwriting the values you are passing in through the command line.

```
onPrepare: function () {
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({
        spec: {
            displayStacktrace: true
        }
    }));
    if (browser.params.Url == 'http://devel/') {
        consoel.log(browser.params.webmaster) //should be abc
        console.log(browser.params.webmaspass) //should be foo
    }
    //(other environments)
    else {
        console.log('-------------error during log in');
    }*/
}
```

Another way you can do this is to set some environment variables before your test run and then you can access them in your scripts by using `process.env.envVariableName` or `${envVariableName}`. Both ways will work.

```
set DEVEL_WEBMASTER=abc
set DEVEL_WEBMASPASS=foo
```

---

```
onPrepare: function () {
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({
        spec: {
            displayStacktrace: true
        }
    }));
    if (browser.params.Url == 'http://devel/') {
        browser.params.webmaster=process.env.DEVEL_WEBMASTER;
        browser.params.webmaspass=process.env.DEVEL_WEBMASPASS;
    }
    //(other environments)
    else {
        console.log('-------------error during log in');
    }*/
}
```

Just remember that if you use this method you would have to set the variables for each session. If you are planning to automate these tests using a CI environment you can just add them there as secret variables (if you have that option) and they will always be there ready and waiting. There will be no need to set them manually during each build.

Comment: I tried on my own the first resolution, but each time I get `{"code": -32000, "message":"Cannot navigate to invalid URL"}`. So I'll try with environment variables method, but should I put it in conf.js or in external file and import it?

Comment: How are you trying to navigate to the url? You might need to set your `baseUrl` also if you haven't done that already. It could be trying to append `http://devel/` to what you already have in there.

Answer (score 0):

What I did it here was create the scripts in my package.json:

```
scripts: {
    "automation-test": "concurrently --raw --kill-others \"./node_modules/.bin/webdriver-manager start\" \"sleep 5 && ./node_modules/.bin/protractor configuration/protractor.config.js\"",
    "automation:pending": "TAGS=@pending npm run automation-test"
}
```

And in my protractor.conf.js I just assign the value to a variable so I can use in my config. Like this:

```
let tags = process.env.TAGS;
```

Then the command that I run is just this:

```
npm run automation:pending
```

but I could pass the TAGS like this as well:

```
npm run automation-test TAGS=@pending
```

Answer (score 0):

**I have not seen the configuration file on the parameters of the command line. you must specify the configuration file:
example: protractor config.js --params ......**

**Do this in your script file:** i have added a config file after the command protractor

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
     "dev-script": "protractor config.js --params.Url=http://devel/ --browser.params.webmaster='' --browser.params.webmaspass=''"
  },
```